# Foreman/Puma isn't using the specified port in dev env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, foreman, puma

I set the port as 3000 in my application.yml (figaro managing env variables)
`rails s` uses port 3000
but when I run `foreman start` (as recommended by Heroku) I get the following output

```
14:53:23 web.1  | started with pid 24425
14:53:23 web.1  | [24425] Puma starting in cluster mode...
14:53:23 web.1  | [24425] * Version 2.11.1 (ruby 2.2.0-p0), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
14:53:23 web.1  | [24425] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
14:53:23 web.1  | [24425] * Environment: development
14:53:23 web.1  | [24425] * Process workers: 2
14:53:23 web.1  | [24425] * Preloading application
14:53:24 web.1  | WARNING: Skipping key "PORT". Already set in ENV.
14:53:25 web.1  | [24425] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
14:53:25 web.1  | [24425] Use Ctrl-C to stop
14:53:25 web.1  | [24425] - Worker 0 (pid: 24426) booted, phase: 0
14:53:25 web.1  | [24425] - Worker 1 (pid: 24427) booted, phase: 0
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

config/application.yml

```
PORT: "3000"
```

- Rails 4.2.0
- Foreman 0.78.0
- Ruby 2.2.0p0
- Puma 2.11.1

Comment: Was your question why your configuration isn't working and how to have `foreman start` default to port 3000, or how to be able to use `foreman` with port 3000? If it's the latter, you can just do it inline by adding `-p $PORT` to your Procfile so it's: `web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT -C config/puma.rb`

Then you can use: `foreman start -p 3000`

Comment: The latter should solve my problem, but the former is my actual question, why isn't foreman using port 3000?

Comment: Also, I tried adding `-p $PORT` inline, but that didn't work, it was still using port 5000, `foreman start -p 3000` worked, but how do I make that work without the command line option?

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but you should be able to use just `foreman start` if you use `web: bundle exec puma  -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development} -C config/puma.rb` in Procfile

Comment: @sid That seems like it should work, but I'm seeing port 5000 used. I'm positive that I have no value for $PORT.

Answer (score 10):

Mystery on the puma port solved.

Put this print in your config/puma.rb

Then you'll see that somehow the port is mysteriously set to 5000 even though it is not in your ENV.

Fix at bottom.

```
puma_port = ENV['PORT'] || 3000
puts "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
puts "puma_port is #{puma_port}"
puts "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ”
```

That prints out

```
16:49:28 web.1  | ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
16:49:28 web.1  | puma_port is 5000
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Then place this line in your Procfile (not the one you use for Heroku). I've got one called `Procfile.dev`

```
web: PORT=3000 bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

And I run it with this command:

```
foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

Comment: Turns out that Foreman sets the $PORT variable to 5000, 5100, 5200, ... for each of the lines in the Procfile, if it was not already set. This is not currently documented anywhere, but after diving deep into its source code it seems that that is what is going on. So either fill in PORT as an env variable, hard-code the puma port in `config/puma.rb` or hard-code the port at the start of the `Procfile` line as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a .foreman file with:

```
port: 3000
```

or a .env file with:

```
PORT=3000
```

Either one should work, then you can just use `foreman start`

Answer (score 2):

`port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000`

This line says that you will attempt to use `ENV['PORT']` first and if that doesn't exist, you will fall back to using `3000` as the port number. So are you defining `PORT` environment variable anywhere prior to `foreman` starting? `config/application.yml` environment variables only will be loaded after the rails server starts, so it's no use defining port number here.

You can try adding

`PORT=3000` in `.env` file in the root of the project directory.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#procfile