# What does ${PORT:-3000} mean in Heroku Procfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, procfile

[Heroku suggests this Procfile command to start Puma on Rails 5 setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#procfile):

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

At first I thought 3000 was a default value, but in fact foreman uses port 5000 if `PORT` is missing in development.

**Question:** What does the notation `${VARIABLE:-3000}` mean?

--

**Update:** It seems like puma is the culprit: [Foreman/Puma isn't using the specified port in dev env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595129)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default value of the `VARIABLE`.

> Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
> word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is
> substituted.

From: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

In this case if the `PORT` variable is not set then its value will be `3000` and similarly if `RACK_ENV` is not set then it will be `development`.

Comment: Any idea why it uses 5000 instead of 3000?

Comment: Have you checked your `.env` file?

Comment: Yes, there is no PORT variable

Comment: When I set PORT=3000 it uses 3000, if I don't set anything it uses 5000. I copy-pasted the Procfile, no typos there.

Comment: Well, you can always log the `PORT` environment variable out somewhere. My assumption is that it has been set somewhere.

Comment: Never mind, thank you, it seems to be an issue with Puma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595129